# Microsoft Flow Custom Connector webhook trigger definition and implementation : 404 not found after flow creation

Tags: azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I'm trying to create a custom connector for my API in Microsoft Flow so users can trigger flows based on a webhook implementation.
The authentication part seems to be working properly (I'm able to create connections). After creating a flow using my custom trigger, it never gets triggered. When checking the data on my end it seems that Flow was **never able to register the subscription properly**.
If I navigate to the management page for the flow, I get the following error message.
[image: There's a problem with the flow's trigger screenshot]
When I click on fix the trigger I get the following details [image: not found error] where the Id parameter matches the id of the resource we're trying to subscribe to.
Here is the trigger definition:

```
{
"/AlertRules/{id}/webhooks": {
      "x-ms-notification-content": {
        "schema": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "Title": {
              "type": "string",
              "description": "Title"
            },
            "Text": {
              "type": "string",
              "description": "Text"
            },
            "Data": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/DataApi.Models.AlertEvent"
              },
              "description": "Data"
            }
          }
        },
        "description": ""
      },
      "post": {
        "responses": {
          "201": {
            "description": "Created",
            "schema": {
                "type": "string"
            }
          }
        },
        "x-ms-trigger": "single",
        "operationId": "NewAlertEvent",
        "summary": "When a new Alert Event is created or updated",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "id",
            "in": "path",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
            "x-ms-visibility": "important",
            "x-ms-dynamic-values": {
              "operationId": "AlertRules.AlertRule.ListAlertRule",
              "value-path": "Id",
              "value-collection": "value",
              "value-title": "Description"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "body",
            "in": "body",
            "required": false,
            "schema": {
              "type": "string",
              "x-ms-visibility": "internal",
              "title": "",
              "x-ms-notification-url": true
            },
            "x-ms-visibility": "internal"
          }
        ]
      }
}
```

The description of my delete operation

```
{
"/AlertRuleSubscriptions({Id})": {
"delete": {
        "tags": [
          "AlertRuleSubscriptions.AlertRuleSubscription"
        ],
        "summary": "Delete entity from AlertRuleSubscriptions",
        "operationId": "AlertRuleSubscriptions.AlertRuleSubscription.DeleteAlertRuleSubscription",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "in": "path",
            "name": "Id",
            "description": "key: Id",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
            "format": "uuid",
            "pattern": "^[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}$",
            "x-ms-docs-key-type": "AlertRuleSubscription"
          },
          {
            "in": "header",
            "name": "If-Match",
            "description": "ETag",
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "204": {
            "description": "Success"
          },
          "default": {
            "$ref": "#/responses/error"
          }
        },
        "x-ms-docs-operation-type": "operation"
      }
}
}
```

And my post operation does reply with a Location header which matches the format of the delete operation described above.
My questions are:

- What is missing in my trigger declaration?
- How can I get more details on the subscription creation and the error Microsoft Flow is generating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some internal discussions with Microsoft we found two main issues.
First I updated the body parameter of the POST request to create the subscription to this.

```
       {
        "name": "body",
        "in": "body",
        "required": false,
        "schema": {
         "type": "object",
         "properties": {
          "callbackUrl": {
           "type": "string",
           "required": true,
           "description": "callbackUrl",
           "x-ms-notification-url": true,
           "x-ms-visibility": "internal"
          }
         }
        }
       }
```

That is because the connector definitions don't support sending the callback URL in the body without using JSON formatting and because Flow was implemented [using the Open API callback specification](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/callbacks/).

Second I updated my API to support the specification mentioned above.