# PowerApps Custom Connector returns 404 in app builder

Tags: odata, powerapps

I'm trying to create a connection to an external OData API from PowerApps.

I've created a custom connector via a Postman collection - the custom connector appears to work correctly in test mode but as soon as I try to consume it in the PowerApp I always get a 404 error popup in the expression editor.

Checking the POST request made to https://europe-001.azure-apim.net/invoke and re-playing it with all headers via Postman results in the same 404 error:

```
{
    "statusCode": 404,
    "message": "Resource not found"
}
```

Testing the API in the PowerApps Swagger editor comes back with the results, but instead of a POST to the above URL where headers are sent with the API endpoint address, a GET is made instead.

If I replay this GET request with the same headers etc, I get the same 404. The only thing that changes per request is `x-ms-client-request-id` so I assume this is to prevent XHR replays.

Am I missing some publishing step for my custom connector?

Has anyone got something like this working?

### Edit:

Interestingly - I tried this with a basic API at `jsonplaceholder.typicode.com` and this works. The API requires no auth and returns data to my Powerapp without an issue.

I'm not sure why this is different from the other custom connector apart from the authentication mechanism.

### Edit edit:

This may be a bug in PowerApps - MS support are looking into it for me and another user stated their connectors stopped working since the October release with the same error.

Comment: Actually I posted your question in my twitter circle & got a response saying almost a MS bug - https://twitter.com/that_API_guy/status/1188942523504480257

Comment: Well, at the moment I can't even seem to use PowerApps studio - it just says `there is a problem with PowerApps studio right now`! I'm not sure if this is a platform issue or not since I've tried this over several weeks, tried recreating the custom connector, re-authing etc etc - all sorts :(

Comment: You may need to take a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/56989373/7920473

Comment: Hey I had the same problem the following steps fixed it for me:

- Download the custom connector json file
- Delete existing connector
- Create New Connector using the downloaded file and gave it another name
- Go to the app ,

Comment: I'll give it a try, Microsoft couldn't understand the issue to the point that I had to seek alternatives to PowerApps. So far it's still not working, I'll try the above though.